# Error:The unintended end of the file. The following elements are not closed: ContentPage., line 31, position 3

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App1.ViewModel"
     x:Class="App1.View.LoginPage" BackgroundColor="#f0f2f5">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:LoginViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Content>
 <StackLayout>
        <Image Source="XamarinLogo.png" ></Image>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="20" WidthRequest="396" HeightRequest="430" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center" >
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Вход на Lockdown" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Title" Margin="0,30,0,10" />
                <Entry  Placeholder="Логин" x:Name="login" Text="{Binding Login}" />
                <Entry Placeholder="Пароль" x:Name ="password" Text="{Binding Password}"  IsPassword="True"/>
                <Label x:Name="LoginMessageLabel" Text="{Binding LoginMessage,Mode=OneWay}" IsVisible="{Binding TurnLoginMessage,Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextColor="Red"></Label>
                <Button x:Name="loginButton" Text="Вход" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="6" BackgroundColor="#1877F2" Margin="10,10,10,10"
                Command="{Binding cmdLogin}">

                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="createAccount" Text="Создать новый аккаунт" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="6" BackgroundColor="#42B72A" Margin="10,10,10,10" Command="{Binding cmdCreateAccount}"/>
                <Label Text="Забыли пароль?" TextColor="#1877F2" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding cmdForgotPassword}"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout></ContentPage.Content>
```

what is the problem?This is my first time working with xamarin, I don't understand what the error is.What is not closed if I closed it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to close every control you create. you forget to close ContentPage

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App1.ViewModel"
     x:Class="App1.View.LoginPage" BackgroundColor="#f0f2f5">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:LoginViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Content>
 <StackLayout>
        <Image Source="XamarinLogo.png" ></Image>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="20" WidthRequest="396" HeightRequest="430" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center" >
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Вход на Lockdown" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Title" Margin="0,30,0,10" />
                <Entry  Placeholder="Логин" x:Name="login" Text="{Binding Login}" />
                <Entry Placeholder="Пароль" x:Name ="password" Text="{Binding Password}"  IsPassword="True"/>
                <Label x:Name="LoginMessageLabel" Text="{Binding LoginMessage,Mode=OneWay}" IsVisible="{Binding TurnLoginMessage,Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextColor="Red"></Label>
                <Button x:Name="loginButton" Text="Вход" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="6" BackgroundColor="#1877F2" Margin="10,10,10,10"
                Command="{Binding cmdLogin}">

                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="createAccount" Text="Создать новый аккаунт" TextColor="White" BorderRadius="6" BackgroundColor="#42B72A" Margin="10,10,10,10" Command="{Binding cmdCreateAccount}"/>
                <Label Text="Забыли пароль?" TextColor="#1877F2" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding cmdForgotPassword}"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout></ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```